# Create a function that generates circular borders with n separate parts and places an event listener on each one. HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

I need to create a series of circles that meet the following pattern:
[Circle Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSsV.jpg)

But I need to generate a function to create a circle divided into n parts, not just 2 that follows the same design pattern as the image. I was able to create 4 circles with that pattern, for that I used the following code:

```css
.circle,
.circle1,
.circle2,
.circle3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.circle1 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.circle2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* splitting the circle into 2, equally sized columns/semi-circles */
  grid-template-areas: 'up1 up2' 'down down';
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle3 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* splitting the circle into 2, equally sized columns/semi-circles */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
li.inner-circle-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -145px 0px 0px -145px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}
li.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -145px 0px 0px -145px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}
li.slide,
li.slide1,
li.slide2,
li.slide3,
li.slide4,
li.slide5,
li.slide6,
li.slide7,
li.slide8,
li.slide9 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.slide,
.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5,
.slide6,
.slide7,
.slide8,
.slide9 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.slide:hover,
.slide1:hover,
.slide2:hover,
.slide3:hover,
.slide4:hover,
.slide5:hover,
.slide6:hover,
.slide7:hover,
.slide8:hover,
.slide9:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.slide1:hover {
  transform: translate(-10px);
}
.slide2:hover {
  transform: translate(10px);
}
.slide.purple,
.slide1.purple,
.slide2.purple,
.slide3.purple,
.slide4.purple,
.slide5.purple,
.slide6.purple,
.slide7.purple,
.slide8.purple,
.slide9.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
.slide3 {
  grid-area: up1;
}
.slide4 {
  grid-area: up2;
}
.slide5 {
  grid-area: down;
}
.inner-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  left: 140px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
      <li class="inner-circle-one"></li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="inner-text"><span id="number">0</span>/1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="circle1">
      <li class="inner-circle"></li>
      <li class="slide1">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide2">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="inner-text"><span id="number1">0</span>/2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="circle2">
      <li class="inner-circle"></li>
      <li class="slide3">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide4">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide5">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="inner-text"><span id="number2">0</span>/3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="circle3">
      <li class="inner-circle"></li>
      <li class="slide6">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide7">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide8">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide9">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="inner-text"><span id="number2">0</span>/4</li>
    </ul>
```

But I want to generate a circle with any number of parts that follow the same layout with a javascript function, with for example:

```
function generateCircleBorders(n) {
 //Put your code here
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Wouldn't canvas or svg be a better option here?

Comment: @j08691 if you think you can do the job like that you can show me that way, I don't have much expirience on those fields. And I need to put event listeners on every border.

Comment: What is the pattern? I was surprised to see that the three had  unequal arcs. Does that mean 5 would have 3 equal above the center and two equal below? And is the user really to have to hit an arc, or can they click the related segment?

Comment: @AHaworth That is correct and I don't know how to make the circle of three with three equal parts following this pattern, that is, three equal parts that are only the edges and that each edge is separated 1gap from the others. It would be ideal if it were like this. But since I don't know how I did it that way, can the function of generating the circle of n parts be done with that design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid a lot of math calculations by making use of CSS rotate and clip path.

You do need a little Javascript, to create the clip path we need the tan of an angle (360 degrees minus the gap required) / number of segments.

This method creates as many segments as are required (set the Javascript const num to the number required), rotates them about the center of the circle, clips them and adds an event listener to each.

Note that this method requires an acute angle, so the number of segments has to be 4 or above. If you need help adding the special code for 1-3 let me know.

```js
const num = 3; //set this to the number required
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.setProperty('--num', num);
container.style.setProperty('--tan', Math.tan(((360 - num * 10) / num) * Math.PI / 180)); //10 is degrees of each gap
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  const segment = document.createElement('div');
  segment.style.setProperty('--n', i);
  segment.id = 'Segment' + (i + 1);
  container.append(segment);
  segment.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(segment.id);
  });
}
container.classList.add('num' + num);
```

```css
.container {
  --d: 50vmin;
  /* the diameter of the circle */
  --bW: 10%;
  /* the width of the border */
  --r: calc(var(--d) / 2);
  width: var(--d);
  height: var(--d);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width: calc(100% - var(--bW));
  height: calc(100% - var(--bW));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container div {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 var(--r), calc(var(--tan) * var(--r)) 0);
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(var(--r)) rotate(calc((360deg / var(--num)) * var(--n)));
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.container.num1 div {
  transform: translateX(0);
  clip-path: none;
}

.container.num2 div {
  clip-path: polygon(3% 0, 0 var(--r), 3% var(--d), var(--d) var(--d), var(--d) 0);
}

.container.num3 div {
  clip-path: polygon(35% 0, 0 var(--r), 35% var(--d), var(--d) var(--d), var(--d) 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect and yes, I need help with for 1-3 code, I guess That I need a different code for that particular case.

Comment: I've added rather hacky code for 1-3. Will hope to be able to come back to it in a few hours (it needs proper angle calculations to make sure the gaps are consistent with the other cases but it may do as a demo).

Answer (score 0):

Using a canvas we can easily draw arcs. The trick is to see if mouse is hover a section, but simple geometry should help (distance and angle).

```js
const size = 200;
const n = 7;
const width = 40;


var radius = size / 2 - width / 2

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);

var arc = 360 / n;
var rad = Math.PI / 180;


function draw_circle(color) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    draw_arc(i, color)
  }
}

function draw_arc(i, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.arc(size * 0.5, size * 0.5, radius, arc * i * rad, arc * (i + 0.95) * rad, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}


draw_circle("black");
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  var cx = ev.offsetX
  var cy = ev.offsetY

  var x = size / 2 - cx;
  var y = size / 2 - cy;

  var distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

  var alpha = (Math.atan2(y, x) / rad + 180) % 360

  var arc = Math.floor(alpha / 360 * n)

  draw_circle("black");
  if (Math.abs(distance - radius) < width / 2) {
    draw_arc(arc, "red");
  }

})
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```