# javascript angle between two coordinates atan and atan2

Tags: javascript, geometry, coordinates, angle

I am working with an array of objects. Each array records the new X, newY, oldX, oldY.

From this, I am trying to calculate the angle between each new coordinate following the [theory](https://qr.ae/pv2HCS) using [Math.atan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan) and [Math.atan2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2). But they seem to produce different results and I am not sure which one should I use.

```js
const allCoOrdinate = [{
    "newX": 455.845577,
    "newY": 383.3440431,
    "oldX": 460.8,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 500.2485855,
    "newY": 444.4595412,
    "oldX": 537.6,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 500.2485855,
    "newY": 520.0024514,
    "oldX": 614.4,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 455.845577,
    "newY": 581.1179495,
    "oldX": 691.2,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 384,
    "newY": 604.4619926,
    "oldX": 768,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 312.154423,
    "newY": 581.1179495,
    "oldX": 844.8,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 267.7514145,
    "newY": 520.0024514,
    "oldX": 921.6,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 267.7514145,
    "newY": 444.4595412,
    "oldX": 998.4,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 312.154423,
    "newY": 383.3440431,
    "oldX": 1075.2,
    "oldY": 360
}, {
    "newX": 384,
    "newY": 360,
    "oldX": 1152,
    "oldY": 360
}];

allCoOrdinate.map((a) => {
    const diffY = a.newY - a.oldY;
    const diffX = a.newX - a.oldX;
    const angleAtan = Math.atan(diffY / diffX) * (180 / Math.PI);
    const angleAtan2 = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX) * (180 / Math.PI);
    a.diffY = diffY, a.diffX = diffX, a.angleAtan = angleAtan, a.angleAtan2 = angleAtan2;
})

console.log(allCoOrdinate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg>
      
    </svg>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Excel produces this.

I want the output in javascript but am extremely confused about what syntax should I use to get accurate results.

[image]

Comment: I recently [answered with a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73326539/3807365) where I was needed to calculate angle from center of circle and `Math.atan2` proved useful - although I had to manipulate it to get it the direction I want (counter-clockwise vs clockwise) so I added 180 degrees. The usefulness is because it handles the "4 quarter" problem for you to give you an angle in the range of 0-360 degrees

Comment: use `atan2(newY-oldY,newX-oldX)` ... `atan(dy/dx)` is only up 180 deg as sign of x,y is lost while `atan2(dy,dx)` is full 360deg ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atan` function gives value in range `-Pi/2..Pi/2` (-90..90 degrees), while `atan2` is intended for full circle range `-Pi..Pi` (look at specifications in `Math` description).

You can see that you result difference is exactly `180=Pi` for cases when angle is in the second and third quarters.

So results are correct, and you just have to interpret them properly. For vectors (direction!) we need angle in full range, while line might be described with half-range angle value provided by `atan`

Answer (score 0):

Use atan2() -- With atan(), you might enter 123/0 and get into mathematical trouble.

"accurate results" -- That depends.  If the points are cities, 2 decimal places are adequate for lat/lng; if you need to distinguish between the GPS location of your daughter and the guy she is kissing, 6 decimal places should do.

The number of decimal places in the result of atan2 is tricker -- we need to see what it will be used for.

If you are drawing graphics on your computer monitor, 4 significant digits everywhere should be plenty.

oldY = 360 -- That is suspiciously like an angle, not a y-value??